# Postsharp 2.0 Aspects not firing with .net 3.5 and visual studio 2008

Tags: postsharp

I recently upgraded to the postsharp 2.0 community edition, and my postsharp aspects are not firing.  Is this a known issue?

Mike

Answer (score 0):

This was a stupid question.  Postsharp 1.5 was trying to process my dlls and failing.